# get table name of resultset Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo, multiple-resultsets

I am using PHP PDO. My stored procedure returns two result sets. Is it possible to name the result sets? In case they are SELECT statements on two tables like,

```
SELECT * FROM A
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM B
```

Is it possible to identify them?

Comment: Don't you know already which result belongs to which table?

Comment: `select 'fromA', * from a` and `select 'fromB', * from b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't name the result sets, although I can't readily think of any reason why you would need to name the result sets... since the number and content of result-sets returned by stored procedures is entirely arbitrary -- and, in fact, needn't be from a table at all (`SELECT NOW() AS server_time;`) the application is required to understand -- in advance -- the nature of the results the server will return, and in what order.

They can be "identified" by their ordinal position in the responses from the server... the first unbounded `SELECT` that executes is what generates what you see as the first result set, the second one to execute generates the second, etc... always.

Stored procedures execute their instructions sequentially, within a single thread, so there's never a chance of the result-sets coming out in any order other than the order in which the `SELECT` statements are encountered in the program flow, no matter how long each query takes.

If the answer -- "no" -- leaves you with an unsolved problem, please consider expanding your question to explain what we're trying to solve.